# How to solve error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

My teacher has given me the following code to produce a sound recorder program with wave visualisation. However im stuck with the errors that are shown below.

.ccp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "resource2.h"

using namespace std;


//Globals for sound wave visualistion

int number, length, byte_samp, byte_sec, bit_samp;

static int sampleRate = 11025;

const int NUMPTS = 11025 * 10;

bool mono = TRUE;

bool PLAY = FALSE;

errno_t wavfile;

char * filename;

int s_rate = 11025;

double limit = 10000.0;

FILE * stream;

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/* Declare procedures */

int readSample(int number,bool leftchannel);

void SaveWavFile(char *FileName, PWAVEHDR WaveHeader);

void Wav(char *c, HWND hWnd);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */

char szAppName[ ] = "Recorder";
```

resource2.h

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED

#define RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED

#define INP_BUFFER_SIZE 16384

#define IDC_RECORD 1

#define IDC_PLAY 2

#define IDC_STOP 3

#define NUM 20000

//defines for menu

#define APP_SAVE 1003

#define APP_EXIT  1004
#endif // RESOURCE_H_INCLUDED
```

I have been getting the errors:

> Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp__waveOutOpen@24
>   referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProcedure(struct HWND**
>   *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)   Error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol **imp__waveInPrepareHeader@12 referenced in function
>   "long __stdcall WindowProcedure(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned
>   int,long)" (?WindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) 1>recorder.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp__waveInOpen@24
>   referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProcedure(struct HWND**
>   *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)

Please tell me how to solve this , i have been scratching my head for hours.

Comment: Your teacher is asking you to write the code...not just run the code. So, try to write function body for the function names given in a .cpp file.

Comment: Why do you put spaces between lines?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't all the code, since those functions weren't called in it. They are Windows functions defined in `winmm.dll`, so link to `winmm.lib`. Exactly how to do that depends on your compiler.